# SSIS Update derived columns to table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, split, conditional-statements, derived

I've been trying to fix some of the data errors in the wrong field and I managed to do it via derived column. My derived columns consist of those fields that have been fixed. How can I update them into the existing table rows which contains those errors of wrong placed fields?

[image]

Comment: With an OLEDB Command transformation.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=ssis+update+table+ole+db+command+example

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the same table which you are bringing in your "OLE DB Source" with fixed value or you want to insert the fixed value to a different destination table or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have table **Test** with columns col_pk, col1, col2, col3, col4 in your source table. **col_pk** being the primary key, and you have errors in **col1** and **col3**.

> I am assuming by "existing table rows which contains those errors of wrong placed fields" you want to update the same table you are using in your OLE DB Source

Now after the Derived Column Transformation say you have corrected the errors and you have 2 new columns col1_new and col3_new

> (You can also give them the same name and replace existing columns,
>   **this replace will be SSIS internal and won't effect your database**, writing this as I was not clear by question and you might be confused
>   in this replace)

What you need to do now:

1. Create a OLE DB Destination task, and link output of Derived Column Transformation as its input
2. In the task, create a new table, say Test_new. It will give you an automatic create option on the basis of input of the OLE DB Destination. (You just need to map col_pk, col1_new and col3_new to the destination)
3. In the control flow, create a Execute SQL Task and there write a query to update Test table like:

   UPDATE Test

   SET col1 = Col1_new,Col2 = Col2_new

   FROM Test

   INNER JOIN Test_new

   ON Test.col_pk = Test_new.col_pk

That's all!